# JQuery: How to connect event to iFrame scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to attach an **event to fire whenever I scroll an iFrame**

I've **tried these with no luck**

```
$('#iframeid').on('scroll', function(){...});

$('#iframeid').contentWindow.on('scroll', function(){...});

$('#iframeid').contents().find('body, html').on('scroll', function(){...});
```

I'm using AngularJs and JQuery.

Comment: Have you tried `$($('#iframeid').contents()).scroll(function(){});`

Comment: @JonathandeM. THANK YOU SO MUCH! It worked. If you post an answer, I'll mark it correct as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the following would do the trick

```
$('#iframeid').contents().scroll(function(){
 // code here
});
```

Comment: The outer `$(...)` turns out to be unnecessary.